# What is this encoding and how do you decode it?

Tags: xml, encoding, xml-serialization, xml-parsing, base64

I'm working with an XML document and within a certain element that deals with setting date and time ranges I have this string that's some for of encoding:

```
<CONTAIN>AQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAnkQAAAAADACeRA</CONTAIN>
```

Does this form of character encoding look familiar to anyone? My first thought was base64 but decoding it as base64 returns garbled text.

I'd love to know how this is encoded and how you would decode it.

Comment: The original looks garbled to me.  I don't see how would expect someone to recognize an encoding by looking at the contents of that tag.

Comment: Doesn't look like anything I recognize.

Comment: @duffymo an average programmer can recognize base64 (ex: aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=) and hexadecimal (ex: 68656c6c6f20776f726c64) by just looking at a small example. At least I can...so I assume that anyone that has experience with this mystery encoding (if it is an actual common encoding) would be able to recognize it by its notable characteristics (such as the presents of lots of upper-case A's).

Comment: @duffymo I wasn't suggesting anything about your programming skills. Merely that it is pretty easy for someone who's seen and worked with certain encodings to recognize them. Please keep comments constructive.

Comment: I don't think my comment was any less constructive than yours.  Were you made a moderator recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely looks like base64 to me, just with a lot of zeros.  Don't convert to a string, convert to byte[] to get 42 bytes.  Which can encode a range expressed as bits.  There are 42 bytes * 8 = 336 bits.  Which could encode 2 weeks * 24 hours or 14 * 24 = 336 distinct hours.  Nice coincidence.

Comment: You nailed it! Turned out to be base64 after all and I've already been able to reverse engineer what the first 1/4 represents which are days of the week. Many thanks!